# Package Retrival is not working

Tags: metadata, package, code, developer, production

We are trying to retrieve the package from Salesforce Developer org While performing the retrieve we are getting errors for the below components.

[sf:retrieve] package.xml - Metadata API received improper input. Please ensure file name and capitalization is correct. Load of metadata from db failed for metadata of type:NetworkBranding and filename

Comment: please use [edit] and include your package.xml (relevant excerpt only)

Comment: Can you check KI (https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003vkDQAQ) and reload if you are using any static resources.